# Differences between these generic statements

Tags: java, generics

What are the differences between these two generic statements? They seem to do the same thing and it appears to not have any effect at compile time because I can use them interchangeably with no errors.

```
class Foo {

}

class FooBar extends Foo {

}


interface FooService {

    Set<? extends Foo> getFooObject();

    <T extends Foo> Set<T> getFooObjectAlternative();

}

class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Override
    Set<FooBar> getFooObject() {
        // works
    }

    @Override
    Set<FooBar> getFooObjectAlternative() {
        // works but you get a warning
    }

    @Override
    Set<Integer> getFooObjectAlternative() {
        // works for some reason!
    }

}
```

Comment: You can write `Set<Foo> f = getFooObject();` with the second version of the method but not with the first version.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That is a pretty big difference. Thanks for pointing it out. I wonder if there are any other differences...

Comment: Returning a `Set<Integer>` should definitely be a compile-time error if the wildcard is `<T extends Foo>`. Are you sure this code is actually what you tested?

Comment: @DanielPryden I don't have any return statements in my code snippets though